# Python find position in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an input string mentioned below.

```
`input="N.ACM_CONTRACT_TR_STATUS,     N.ACM_REVIEW_DDQ,     N.ACM_IS_GO_IND,   AS  N.ACM_CHARITY_REGISTERED_IND"`
```

The output should be as below : 'AS' keyword should be removed. How can I find the position of the comma occurring just before ' AS '. Is there a method in python other than find() which works similar as INSTR in Oracle.

```
"N.ACM_CONTRACT_TR_STATUS,     N.ACM_REVIEW_DDQ,     N.ACM_IS_GO_IND,    N.ACM_CHARITY_REGISTERED_IND"`
```

Comment: Why find the comma, when you can directly remove the `AS` - `input = input.replace(' AS ', ' ')`. Note: I would avoid using variables that hide builtin in functions, i.e. I would not use `input` as a variable name.

Comment: this is just an example. I have some values like  A, B, X||Y||Z|| AS C for which I want A,B,C in the result. My objective is not just to remove 'AS', it is to remove all the characters from " ," occurred just before " AS "  to " AS"

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = "N.ACM_CONTRACT_TR_STATUS,     N.ACM_REVIEW_DDQ,     N.ACM_IS_GO_IND,   AS  N.ACM_CHARITY_REGISTERED_IN"
re.sub(r",(\s+)AS(\s+)", r"\1,\2", s)
```

Comment: This works if you make the replacement string a raw string: `r"\1,\2"`
Otherwise you get
`'N.ACM_CONTRACT_TR_STATUS,     N.ACM_REVIEW_DDQ,     N.ACM_IS_GO_IND\x01,\x02N.ACM_CHARITY_REGISTERED_IN'`

Comment: Corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The comment on this post is correct; I apologize, I am very tired.

```
import re

text="N.ACM_CONTRACT_TR_STATUS,     N.ACM_REVIEW_DDQ,     N.ACM_IS_GO_IND,   AS  N.ACM_CHARITY_REGISTERED_IND"
# Matches comma, any whitespace between comma and 'AS', and 'AS' itself,
# but only if 'AS' is a word in its own right.
unwanted_chars_re = re.compile(r",\s*AS\b")
new_text = unwanted_chars_re.sub('', text)
```

The new string is `'N.ACM_CONTRACT_TR_STATUS,     N.ACM_REVIEW_DDQ,     N.ACM_IS_GO_IND  N.ACM_CHARITY_REGISTERED_IND'`.

Comment: This one would apply to anything starting with "AS".  Also, using `input` is considered bad practice and would make pylint yell.